# Сигналы в Linux: послать сигнал потоку. Проблема: поток не завершается

Tags: linux, c, signal

Задача: есть процесс. от него создается 2 потока. Через n секунд послать сигнал, по которому должен завершиться один из потоков.
Этот поток не завершается.

Мой код выглядит так и я не могу понять в чем ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <time.h> 

static void handler( int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context ) 
{ 
   printf( "\nSig coming: sig=%d; tid=%lu\n", signo, pthread_self() ); 
}; 

void* threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 ( void* data ) 
{ 
   sigset_t localsig;
   if (sigemptyset(&localsig))
    perror( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 error" ); 
   if (sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &localsig, NULL ))
    perror( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 error" ); 
   printf( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 pause\n");
   pause();
   printf( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 end\n");     
   return NULL; 
};
void* threadfunc( void* data ) 
{ 
   sigset_t localsig;
   if (sigfillset(&localsig))
    perror( "threadfunc error" );
   if (sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &localsig, NULL ))
    perror( "threadfunc error" );
   printf( "threadfunc pause\n");
   pause();
   printf( "threadfunc end\n" );   
   return NULL; 
};

int main() 
{   
   sigset_t sig;   
   const int thrnum = 2;

   if (sigemptyset(&sig))
    perror( "main error" );
   if (sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sig, NULL ))
    perror( "main error" );

   printf("main + %d threads : waiting fot signal %d; pid=%d; tid(main)=%lu\n", thrnum, SIGUSR1, getpid(), pthread_self() ); 

   struct sigaction act; 
   act.sa_mask = sig; 
   act.sa_sigaction = handler; 
   act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
   if( sigaction( SIGUSR1, &act, NULL ) < 0 ) 
    perror( "set signal handler error " ); 

   pthread_t pthr; 
   pthread_create( &pthr, NULL, threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1, NULL ); 
   pthread_create( &pthr, NULL, threadfunc, NULL );

   int sec = 1;
   while (sec < 4)
   {
    printf("sec: %d\n", sec);
    sleep(1);
    sec++;  
   }

   kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);

   while (1)
   {}

};
```

Comment: Это ничего, что у вас не дочерние *процессы*, а потоки без pid?

Comment: sanmai собственно, уже ответил, но если не очень понятно, то поясняю: Вы создаёте **нити**, а сигнал можно послать с помощью функции *kill* только **процессу**.  То, что у вас написано в вызове *kill* - это самоубийство родительского процесса. А принудительное завершение нити - это отдельная и большая тема.

Comment: Рискну дать совет: если у Вас эта программа - не учебное задание, начало разработки чего-то серьёзного, то не используёте нити! Если при работе

Comment: можно сделать так, чтобы обработчик в выбранном потоке исполнялся (`pthread_kill`), но эффекты сигнала (stop, continue) всё равно ко всему процессу относятся. Всегда лучше если поток *кооперативно* выходит (силовое прекращение выполнения потока обычно нежелательно, к нестабильной ситуации ведёт).

Comment: `То, что у вас написано в вызове kill - это самоубийство родительского процесса` - это буквально "выстрел себе в ногу" )))

Answer (score 1):

Рискну дать правильный ответ. Вписал всего две строчки.
Нужно бликировать SIGUSR1 для главного потока и разблокировать для нити которую вы хотите таким образом завершить.
Добавил всего лишь два раза **sigaddset(&localsig, SIGUSR1 );** с коментариями.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <time.h> 

static void handler( int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context ) 
{ 
   // Using printf in signal handler can cause UB on slow systems. Use it only for debugging. 
   // printf( "\nSig coming: sig=%d; tid=%lu\n", signo, pthread_self() ); // Using printf in signal ha
}; 

void* threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 ( void* data ) 
{ 
   sigset_t localsig;
   if (sigemptyset(&localsig))
    perror( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 error" ); 

   sigaddset( &localsig, SIGUSR1 );  //!< Unblock the signal for the  thread

   if (sigprocmask( SIG_UNBLOCK, &localsig, NULL ))
    perror( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 error" ); 
   printf( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 pause\n");
   pause();
   printf( "threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1 end\n");     
   return NULL; 
};
void* threadfunc( void* data ) 
{ 
   sigset_t localsig;
   if (sigfillset(&localsig))
    perror( "threadfunc error" );
   if (sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &localsig, NULL ))
    perror( "threadfunc error" );
   printf( "threadfunc pause\n");
   pause();
   printf( "threadfunc end\n" );   
   return NULL; 
};

int main() 
{   
   sigset_t sig;   
   const int thrnum = 2;

   if (sigemptyset(&sig))
    perror( "main error" );
   sigaddset( &sig, SIGUSR1 ); //!< Block the signal for the  thread
   if (sigprocmask( SIG_BLOCK, &sig, NULL ))
    perror( "main error" );

   printf("main + %d threads : waiting fot signal %d; pid=%d; tid(main)=%lu\n", thrnum, SIGUSR1, getpid(), pthread_self() ); 

   struct sigaction act; 
   act.sa_mask = sig; 
   act.sa_sigaction = handler; 
   act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; 
   if( sigaction( SIGUSR1, &act, NULL ) < 0 ) 
    perror( "set signal handler error " ); 

   pthread_t pthr; 
   pthread_create( &pthr, NULL, threadfuncWithSignalSigUSr1, NULL ); 
   pthread_create( &pthr, NULL, threadfunc, NULL );

   int sec = 1;
   while (sec < 4)
   {
    printf("sec: %d\n", sec);
    sleep(1);
    sec++;  
   }

   kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);

   while (1)
   {}

};
```

Comment: Для сигнала **потоку** надо вызывать [pthread_kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html)

Comment: это довольно грязный метод с подводными камнями... я не уверен, что он будет работать за пределами linux... правильным решением было бы использовать `pthread_kill()`... ЗЫ: к делу не относится, но `printf` использовать в обработчике сигнала нельзя...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вообще-то конечно, `printf` в обработчике писать не стоит. Но конкретная программка в linux (а нам сейчас что-то еще нужно?) не сломается.

Comment: @avp, да, но если быть занудой, то на какой-нить о-о-о-очень медленной системе, на которой потоки за 4 секунды не успеют напечатать свои `printf`'ы перед `pause` и сигнал прилетит во время его выполнения возможно всё что угодно вплоть до дедлока на спине... понятно, что в мелком учебном примере нет ничего страшного, но побрюзжать всё равно хочется =)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ага, теоретически `deadlock` (или какая-нибудь бяка на нереентерабельном мьютексе), но больше тут ломаться вроде нечему. Однако, лишних знаний не бывает, может потенциальные читатели запомнят и будут задумываться о коде обработчика

Comment: Поправил код. Закоментировал вызов printf и дописал, что бы использовали только для отладки. 
А то ведь комментарии редко читают нонче. Лучше сразу предоставить корректный код. А то ведь так  и скопируют себе в проект.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали потоки, а дали сигнал процессу. Причём себе. Один процесс может состоять из множества потоков. И у этих потоков идентификатор процесса - один, а идентификаторы потока - разные.

При создании потоков вы записали их код в одну переменную **pthread_t pthr;**. А для общения с потоками их номера должны храниться отдельно. Создаём две переменные **pthread_t pthrSig;** и **pthread_t pthrFun;**

Чтобы подать сигнал потоку нужно использовать другие функции : **pthread_cond_signal** например. Создаём ещё дополнительно замок для безопасного использования работы сигналов. И указатель на структуру с замком и сигналом передаём аргументом в эти потоки.

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -Winline -Wshadow -Wpedantic -Wconversion -std=c11 -pthread signalth.c -o signalth
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 

typedef struct sCondMutex CondMutex ;

struct sCondMutex {
  pthread_cond_t cond ;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex ;
} ;

void* threadfunc2 ( void* data ) 
{ 
  CondMutex * const comu = data ;
   printf("threadfunc2 : жду сигнал ; процесс = %d; "
     "поток(threadfunc2) = %lx\n", getpid(), pthread_self() ); 
   printf( "threadfunc2 пауза\n");
   if( pthread_cond_wait(&comu->cond,&comu->mutex))
     fputs("threadfunc2 : pthread_cond_wait error" , stderr);
   printf( "threadfunc2 принял сигнал\n");     
   if( pthread_mutex_unlock(& comu->mutex))
     fputs("threadfunc2:pthread_mutex_unlock error\n",stderr);
   return NULL; 
}
void* threadfunc( void* data ) 
{ 
  CondMutex * const comu = data ;
   printf("threadfunc : жду сигнал ; процесс = %d; поток(threadfunc) = %lx\n",
    getpid(), pthread_self() ); 
   printf( "threadfunc пауза\n");
   if( pthread_cond_wait(&comu->cond,&comu->mutex))
     fputs("threadfunc : pthread_cond_wait error" , stderr);
   printf( "threadfunc принял сигнал\n" );   
   if( pthread_mutex_unlock(& comu->mutex))
     fputs("threadfunc:pthread_mutex_unlock error\n",stderr);
   return NULL; 
}

int main() 
{   
   printf("main : процесс = %u\n",getpid());
   printf( "main : поток = %lx\n", pthread_self() ); 
   
   CondMutex comu ;
   if( pthread_cond_init(& comu.cond,0))
     fputs("main:pthread_cond_init error\n",stderr);
   if( pthread_mutex_init(& comu.mutex,0))
     fputs("main:pthread_mutex_init error\n",stderr);
   
   pthread_t pthrSig; 
   pthread_create( &pthrSig, NULL, threadfunc2, & comu ); 
   printf("main : pthrFun2 %lx\n", pthrSig ) ;
   pthread_t pthrFun; 
   pthread_create( &pthrFun, NULL, threadfunc, & comu );
   printf("main : pthrFun %lx\n", pthrFun ) ;

   int sec = 1;
   while (sec < 4)
   {
    printf("сек: %d\r", sec);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    sec++;  
   }

   if(pthread_cond_signal(&comu.cond))
     fputs("main:0.pthread_cond_signal\n",stderr);
   
   sec = 1;
   while (sec < 4)
   {
    printf("сек: %d\r", sec);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    sec++;  
   }
   
   if(pthread_cond_signal(&comu.cond))
     fputs("main:1.pthread_cond_signal\n",stderr);
   
   sec = 1;
   while (sec < 4)
   {
    printf("сек: %d\r", sec);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    sec++;  
   }
   
   fputs("main:пока..\n",stdout);

}
```

$ ./signalth

```
main : процесс = 18534
main : поток = 7fa824bf3740
main : pthrFun2 7fa824425700
main : pthrFun 7fa823c24700
threadfunc : жду сигнал ; процесс = 18534; поток(threadfunc) = 7fa823c24700
threadfunc пауза
threadfunc2 : жду сигнал ; процесс = 18534; поток(threadfunc2) = 7fa824425700
threadfunc2 пауза
threadfunc принял сигнал
threadfunc2 принял сигнал
main:пока..
```

Смотрим номер процесса 18534 у потоков один общий, а номера потоков индивидуальные : ..3740 , ..4700 , ..5700